# how to share a Photo Or link on facebook wall without using FBSDKShareDialog from native ios app

Tags: ios, facebook, integration

I want to post some photos Or Link on user Facebook wall without using FBSDKShareDialog . I am already post With using the FBSDKSharePhoto And FBSDKShareDialog default dialog from facebook. for that I do the below code

```
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
photo.image = self.imgView.image;
photo.userGenerated = YES;
FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
content.photos = @[photo];
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                             withContent:content
                                delegate:(id)self];
```

But, this code open the Default FB dialog. So, how can I directly post the link and photos ON user's wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SLComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/index.html) of default iOS Social Framework

```
#import <Social/Social.h>

- (IBAction)postToFacebook:(id)sender {
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        [controller setInitialText:@"Post from my iPhone app"];
        [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourlink.com"]];
        [controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook-image.jpg"]];
        [controller setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {

        switch (result) {
             case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                 NSLog(@"Post Canceled");
                 break;
             case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                 NSLog(@"Post Sucessful");
                 break;

             default:
                 break;
         }
        }];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];

    }
}
```

Documentation for Facebook Sharing. : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

Through Graph API :

1) [Post image on facebook wall using graph api iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214774/post-image-on-facebook-wall-using-graph-api-iphone-sdk)

2) [Photo Upload to own wall via iOS Graph API with user's location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483157/photo-upload-to-own-wall-via-ios-graph-api-with-users-location)

3) http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/facebook-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-facebook-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app

Comment: this works same as a FBSDKSharedialog. But for that we must have login system facebook account. without login in sysytem account it's not work ,

Comment: @Hirenkanetiya yes, you have to login with facebook account from settings

Comment: is their any way to post  using FBSDK Graph API ?in latest FacebookSDK,please suggest .

Comment: If I will find then I will tell you. You said without FBShareDialog.

Comment: yes, without FBShareDialog ,i want to use a FBSDKOpenGraph Api for sharing the photos and Link...Because with this we need not to login system account every time.